# Where is Visual Studio 2013 Extensibility VSIX Project Template

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsix

Both of these articles talk about how to develop extensions for VS2013, but both presume that you have an extension project type available

- [Extending the Visual Studio Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/esk3eey8.aspx)
- [Creating Extensions By Using the VSIX Project Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd885241.aspx)

As of 11/9/13, there are already [544 extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=VisualStudioVersion&f%5B0%5D.Value=12.0&f%5B0%5D.Text=Visual%20Studio%202013) for VS2013 in the gallery, so I'm guessing it's possible, but I can't find the template anywhere.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Found It!  You need to download the

## [Visual Studio 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758)

Once installed, the project template will appear here:

[image: demo]

Comment: I had the VS 2013 SDK installed, but still couldn't find it. Turns out I was looking for VSIX Project in the Other Project Types -> Extensibility menu, instead of Visual C# -> Extensibility. Thanks for the screenshot!

Comment: Oddly for me your link didn't work, I had to use the Canadian version https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40758 - no idea if that's a temporary glitch...

Comment: I'm unable to download the VS2013 SDK from above link, I also tried to google around, all URL redirected to MS website with 404. any help?

Comment: The download page is not available any more. Download from this URL - https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=1436 (Required to sign in) or in VS 2013 > Extension, search for SDK and click "download" button on "Visual Studio 2013 SDK" which will redirect you to above page

Answer (score -3):

First install the Visual Studio 2013 SDK. It can me easily found on MS.

Comment: On SO there is no need to duplicate answers.  The accepted answer already provides all this information and more.