# Extensibility Project Type does not exist with VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vs-extensibility, project-template

In my Visual Studio 2013, Extensibility Project Template is not found under "**Visual C#**" and "**Other Project Types**". Could you please guide me to enable this project type with Visual Studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is Visual Studio 2013 Extensibility VSIX Project Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910724/where-is-visual-studio-2013-extensibility-vsix-project-template)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install [Visual Studio 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758). Additional project templates will appear in Visual C# - Extensibility and Other Project Types - Extensibility.