# `Extensibility` group is missing in Visual C++ 2013 (creating custom add-in)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have an Visual Studio C++ 2013 installed (**not** an Express edition).

I would like to create an custom add-in, according to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/324611/Extending-Visual-Studio-Part-2-Creating-Addins

The tutorial here is made for C#, but I guess it's also possible to create an add-in for VC++.

However, when I go to `File -> New project -> Other project types` the `Extensibility` group is missing:

[image]

How it looks in the tutorial:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910724/where-is-visual-studio-2013-extensibility-vsix-project-template You need to install the VS SDK.

Comment: Thanks man :) Can you make an answer from it? I was searching the SO for the solution earlier, but did not find this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the Visual Studio SDK. See [Where is Visual Studio 2013 Extensibility VSIX Project Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910724/where-is-visual-studio-2013-extensibility-vsix-project-template). This should give you the extensibility option. It may also be hiding under `VC++ -> Extensibility` as opposed to `Other Project Types -> Extensibility`.